# What happens when I iuse validation_split in model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, validation, machine-learning, keras

When `model.fit()` is called if the parameters `shuffle` and `validation_split` are set to `True` and `.25` respectively will the data set aside for validation always be the same or will the validation data be changed after every epoch?

```
model.fit(train_x,
          train_y,
          batch_size = 32,
          epochs = 1000,
          verbose = 1,
          shuffle = True,
          validation_split = .25)
```

Answer (score 0):

The validation data will stay the same every epoch. If you stop the code and restart it the split will change.

Answer (score 0):

You will have the same validation data (last 25% of your main dataset). You can test it by the code below:

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

trainX = np.zeros((1000, 1))
trainy = np.array(np.arange(10000)).reshape(1000, 10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input((1, )))
model.add(Dense(10))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(0)
model.compile(opt, 'mae')

model.fit(trainX, trainy, epochs = 10, shuffle = True, validation_split = 0.2)
```